# Confused how to use select_related or the SelectRelatedMixin

Tags: django

```
class Board(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return F'{self.author.username} {self.create_date} {self.pk}'


class Problem(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    problem = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.problem[:30]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return
```

The idea is I have a Board and then several Problems associated with it.

I want to make a classView + template to drilldown the detail of a single board.  like `/board/187`

The output would look like:

- BOARD:  IT Issues Problems:

  1) Old servers

  2) No UPC

  3) Static discharges

I made a class-based view to generate the Board.  My idea was that the board_detail.html would have an `{{ include "board/_problem.html" }}` tag that would then use a `ListView` derivative to enumerate all the `Problem`s associated with that `Board`.

I wasn't very clear on how to do this. I thought I could use a `SelectRelatedMixin` in the Problem's class, so that I could then have access to fields in the template something like `for problem in board.problems` kind of structure. But this doesn't seem to be working.  (`SelectRelatedMixin` comes from [django-braces](https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/other.html#selectrelatedmixin))

I'm hazy on how this work all should be put together. In fact, I am not even sure how to do it with the original `select_related()` method.  I guess I should know how to do it with either really, in order to have a full understanding.

Here are the two cbv's I made in my attempt.

```
class Problem(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    problem = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.problem[:30]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return

class BoardUpdateView(SelectRelatedMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Board
    fields = ['author']
    select_related = (Problem,)

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if "pk" not in self.kwargs:
            self.kwargs['pk'] = None
        obj, created = Board.objects.get_or_create(pk=self.kwargs['pk'],
                                                       defaults={'author': self.request.user})
        return obj
```

But maybe this is totally the wrong approach.  Instead perhaps I should somehow pass the `Board.pk` to the included `ProblemList.html` so that it can genereate a list of appropriate objects that way?

Comment: If it's not obvious how to achieve some task with the generic class based views, I would recommend writing a function based view instead. It generally results in more maintainable and explicit code. Overriding the CBVs is hard without a good knowledge of the extensive inheritance tree.

Comment: I think my case is a very typical thing to do, it's just that I'm not experienced with Django.

Comment: Django has no `SelectRelatedMixin`. Please tell us where it came from or show us its source code.

Comment: @knbk it comes from django-braces.  But I am happy to do it with orthodox django code select_related()

Answer (score -1):

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CompleteView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

```
board = self.get_object()
# print(F"problem is what? {problem}")
context['problems'] = board.problem_set.all().order_by('pk')

return context
```

working with `get_object()` inside `get_context_data` was the answer.